# Could not load type 'newVersion_Default'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, compiler-errors

Upon trying to build the page Default.aspx I get the error:

> Error 5   Could not load type
>   'newVersion_Default'. \server1\d$\newVersion\Default.aspx

The content page is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="newVersion_Default" MasterPageFile="Main.master" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="Main.master" %>

<asp:Content id="Content2" contentplaceholderid="mainContent" runat="server"> 

    <h1>Welcome to this Page</h1>

    <div class="tabWrapper">
        <div class="tab"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
        <div class="tab"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></div>
        <div class="tab tabSelected"><a href="#">Something Els wef wef w efe</a></div>
        <div class="tab"><a href="#">Help!</a></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>                
</asp:Content>
```

And the code behind is empty!

```
public partial class newVersion_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
}
```

This is probably a newbie error but any help appreciated :)

I can't rebuild the whole project yet because there's some other crap in the folders that is classic ASP which wont build and throw errors, so I have to build each page at a time, will this cause problems?

Comment: Is it web app project or web site project?

Comment: It's an add on for a classic ASP website, I opened that website with open website in VS2008, then just added a new folder in, 'newversion'.  It worked fine before until I created the master page and then linked it to that.  It built fine as a standalone page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of Web app:

Try use a namespace:

```
Inherits="MySite.newVersion_Default"

namespace MySite
{
    public partial class newVersion_Default : System.Web.UI.Page { }
}
```

---

In case of Web site:

Use `CodeFile` instead of `CodeBehind`

Comment: Still not luck, same error.  I've namespaced the master page and the default page.

Comment: I had this issue and changing it from CodeBehind to CodeFile fixed it. thanks